# Creating a table in a while loop

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I am probably missing something obvious, but I am stuck. I am writing a code on Mathematica for Newton's method, and I need to print out a table for the iteration, approximation root, residual, and the absolute value of the difference between the current and previous approximation. I set a threshold already, and I am pretty much done. However, I can't print out the table. I printed out the values for each iteration in separate lists. I want to print them out in tuples of 4 so that I can make the table and use the command Grid. I just can't find a command that does it. Here is my code and my output. I just need my values in a table. I am attaching my code as a picture to this post. PLEASE HELP! 
Thank you [image]

Comment: `Print` tosses its result outside the *Mathematica* universe, making it hard to recover. For this kind of problem, I usually write a function that takes the result of an iteration and produces a new result, and then feed it (along with a starting state) to `NestWhileList`.

Comment: what do you mean write a function? I want to try saving everything, but I do not know how. I tried creating an empty list and then appending my results from the while loop to that list. It does not work. Is there a better format to do that?

Comment: Something like `f[{thing1_,thing2_}]:={new1,new2}` where `new1` and `new2` are expressions that compute the new values from the old ones, `thing1` and `thing2`.

Comment: `NestWhileList` manages the list construction for you, so you don't have to worry about how to do it. Usually, in *Mathematica*, building lists step by step in code is the hard way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := x*Exp[-x] - .16064
newt[x_] := x - f[x]/f'[x]
m = {}; x = 3; err = 10^-10;
Do[x0 = x; x = newt[x0]; 
 m = Flatten[{m, {{i, x0, x, f[x], Abs[x - x0]}}}, 1]; 
 If[Abs[x - x0] <= err, Break[]];, {i, 100}]

m // TableForm
```

[image: fig1]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend code similar to this

```
ClearAll[x, x0, x1, i, f];
f[x_] := x/Exp[x] - 0.16064;
newt[x_] := x - f[x]/f'[x];
i = 0; x0 = 0; x1 = 3;
Reap[ While[i <= 100 && Abs[x0 - x1] > 10^-5,
  x0 = x1; x1 = newt[x0]; i++;
  Sow[{i, x0, x1, f[x1], Abs[x0 - x1]}]
]][[2, 1]]
```

Of course, there are other ways in Mathematica but this is easy.